# How do i create an array for zip codes to enter in a search bar

Tags: arrays, loops, cypress

I am looking to create an array to store multiple entries for a search bar,
for example entering zip codes into the search bar, but and array that stores say 5-10 zip codes

I know how to retrieve the search bar with .get and .click to allow text entry but am unsure how to create and use an array to make the test run through all elements in the array

Answer (score 2):

Cypress tests are written in javascript - you can create an array then loop through it:

```
const zips = ['00000','12345','99999'];

zips.forEach( (zip) => {
    cy.get('#yourElement).type(zip)';
 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code using Google search bar. I just looped through the array using vanilla javascript:

```
const searchTerms = ['cypress', 'puppeteer', 'cucumber'];

describe('Solving stackoverflow question', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.google.com/');
  })

  it('Google search', () => {
    for (const term of searchTerms) {
        cy.get('[aria-label="Search"]').clear()
          .type(`${term}{enter}`);
        cy.log(`Searched ${term}`);
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to manage Test data from [fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture).

First, create a file under fixtures folder `zip.json`. This file will contain our array of zip codes.

```js
["12345", "434343", "232525"]
```

And then in your tests, you can directly write:

```js
cy.fixture('zip.json').then(testdata => {
  testdata.forEach(zipCode => {
    cy.get('element').type(zipCode)
  })
})
```